# How to get perl script to generate every combination of two variables

Tags: perl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings; #Always use these!
my @no = (1 .. 100); 
foreach(@no) { 
print   "\#world" . $_ . " \{
        background: url(/images/1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
        float: left;
        width: 1%;
        height: 2%;
        position: absolute;
        top: " . $_ . "\%;
        left: " . $_ . "\%;
        z-index: -1;
        margin-top: -10px;
        margin-left: -10px;
    \}

    \#world" . $_ . ":hover \{
        background-position: 0 -20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    \}"; 
}
```

currently this perl script outputs `#world1, top: 1%; left: 1%;` where the percentages are the same. How can i modify the script to output `world(1 through to 100) top: 1%; left: (1% through to 100%)%; world(101 through to 201) top: 2%; left: (1% through to 100%)%;` up to `world(19001 through to 20000) top: 100%; left: (1% through to 100%)%;`

Comment: TLP gives you your answer below.  You can make your code a lot cleaner by just putting the variables within your quotes (you don't need to concatenate as you're doing), or do a `man perlop` and look for here-doc documentation (search for `<<EOF`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add a unique number for `$world` for every top/left value pair.

```
my $world = 1;
for my $top (1 .. 100) {
    for my $left (1 .. 100) {
         # print here... world$world top = $top, left = $left...
         $world++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want world 1 .. 100, 101 .. 201 and 19001 .. 20000? And top/left 1 .. 100 each?

Comment: yes, but I dont know how to do it because it's not a third loop?

Comment: You need to clarify, as your text is ambiguous. Exactly what ranges do you want for world?

Comment: No, I just need the two loops with each of the 20,000 results labelled "world1...world20000"

Comment: Let's continue this [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1691/how-to-get-perl-script-to-generate-every-combination-of-two-variables)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to talk in the chat

Comment: Yeah, I got the same message.. that's silly. Oh well. So, your last comment does not really clarify. You say you dont want 20000 loops for world, but you want 1 .. 20000 for world. To me, that is a contradiction. Do you want to actually print "world1, world2, world3 .. world20000" for each of the 10,000 top/left value pairs?

Comment: no, for top/left=1,1 I would like world1, for top/left=1,2 world 2, top/left=1,3 world 3 all the way up to top/left=100,99 world19999 and top/left=100,100 world20000 Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Oh, so you mean that we use two loops, but add 1 to world up to 20000.. that does not compute, my friend. 100x100=10,000. Your top/left pairs will run short before your world reaches 20000.

Comment: my mistake. then how do I get world1...world10000?